# CustomValidator ServerValidate dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to validate a dropdownlist and if the selectedValue = "0" then the Isvalid = false but it doesn't seem to be working does any one know what todo here

```
protected void valCountry_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Value == "0"))
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
        MasterPage master = Page.Master;
        AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender popupExtender = (AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)master.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1");
        popupExtender.Show();
    }
}

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please Choose" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="New Zealand" Text="New Zealand" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valCountry" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="ddlCountries"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="You must select a Country."
    SetFocusOnError="true"
    ValidationGroup="UserInfo" 
    OnServerValidate="valCountry_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ddlCountry.options[ddlCountry.selectedIndex].value` instead of `e.Value`.